# Synchronizing Eclipse project on Thumbdrive with PC

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, usb-drive

I have a thumb drive (memory stick, flash drive, etc.) on which I use for my projects when I am away from my home PC.  Currently I am accessing my Eclipse project directly from my thumb drive when connected to my PC.

I would like to copy my files to the PC, develop on the PC, then "synchronize" with the thumb drive (update files on the thumb drive).  I also need the reverse process too:  synchronize thumb drive files with files on PC.

I have looked at the FileSync plugin, but it specifically says it is one-way.

How can I synchronize my Eclipse project both directions (PC to thumb drive and thumb drive to PC) on demand (I don't need this done automagically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a DVCS (git, hg), make sure to sync repositories when you're changing your work location. This will even let you work on the same file in multiple places and merge the result.
2. Use [Unison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison_(file_synchronizer))

Comment: Although this is the proper process, I'm cautious about using `git` after using professional CMS systems like PVCS and ClearCase.  I like systems that are robust and allow labels.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: Considering git is used successfully for very large and very active code bases, robustness is not a problem. And git goes well beyond just supporting tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Windows, so how about [Sync Butler](http://syncbutler.org/)?  Syncs the chosen folders automatically when the flash drive is plugged in.

Comment: +1 I like Sync Butler, it's prettier than the utility I wrote.  However, Sync Butler does not have the option to exclude directories, such as those containing object files (which are usually platform dependent).